# Smarten up vs Wise up

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between **Smarten up** and **Wise up**? is telling someone to **wise up** the same as telling them to **smarten up?**

For example:

> You need to **smarten up** and do your job better.
>
> You need to **wise up** and do your job better.

Comment: In Britain, if your boss told you to "smarten up", you'd get a haircut, shave, and put on a suit. Elswhere, the meaning could be different.

Answer (score 1):

In British English at least, *smarten* isn't usually used for getting smarter in the sense of intelligence, but rather in the sense of appearance.

***Smartening up*** is making yourself more presentable for contexts that expect business or formal dress, or changing the style of clothing and personal presentation more towards business or formal when it currently is not. For example, if you're dressed "smart casual" and change something a little to get more towards smart, even if it's not fully business dress, that might be referred to as having "smartened up".

I can't speak for American English.